# How to remember input form data in CodeIgniter (CI) after redirect than come again to same page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies, helper, form-data

I've Googled and there are many ways of doing this in PHP itself, JavaScript/ jQuery/ AJAX and CodeIgniter session data/ flash data.

But I prefer to have do this within CI perdefied library/helper like laravel OLD helper. My form is very large and contains different elements like text inputs, dropdowns, radios, etc. However I tried the following on my inputs in the View (MVC).
for example I have a form which have some filed like below

Example:

```
<form method="post" >
        <input type='text' class="form-control"  value="name" />
        <input type='text' class="form-control"  value="" />
        <input type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name' value="<?=set_value('last_name')?>" />
    <select name="select">
        <option value="1">Select 1</option>
        <option value="2">Select 2</option>
        <option value="3">Select 3</option>

    </select>
    <a href="/add-new-select">Add new Select value </a>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now when I click on Add new select they will redirect me to another page where I will create a new select( select 4) after successful creation i will redirect to my form.

Now How can I fill all my input with his old data

I have tried set_value but its only worked on form submit.I can fix this issue using session/cookies but it will be a huge process and fragment the code. Are there any alternative ways? Examples are welcome!

Comment: You already have your answer for your "preferred" method, use sessions. But then you seem to know this is bad and you have already looked this up on Google regarding using AJAX... So what are you asking? You've already been looking up examples. Try some and if you get stuck on the code then ask.

Comment: Actually I am looking for some CI library/helper which is avail to achieve my Goal !

Answer (score 0):

we can not set the values using set_values() function here because set_values() function works only when we validate the form and form validation fails.
here you can use session or cookie for setting the value and you can get the values after redirection.